# Convert String to two Strings with stream

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a String as below,

```
String str = "ID1_RELID1, ID2_RELID2,ID3_RELID3";
```

I want to convert it into two Strings as below,

```
String ids = "'ID1','ID2','ID3'";
String relids = "'RELID1','RELID2','RELID3'";
```

i.e spliting each value by _ and joing with comma.

I tried below code,

```
String str = "ID1_RELID!, ID2_RELID2,ID3_RELID3";
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
        .collect(toMap(e -> e.split("_")[0], e -> e.split("_")[1]));
String ids = map.keySet().stream().map(e -> "'" + e + "'").collect(joining(","));
String relids = map.values().stream().map(e -> "'" + e + "'").collect(joining(","));
```

Its working fine but can we do it in min possible iterations ??

Comment: Is using streams mandatory?

Comment: I know, we can easily achieve this without stream but I was just getting my hands dirty with streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mutable reduction that performs the same in one pipeline. You assess it:

```
List<StringBuilder> stringBuilders = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
    .map(s -> s.split("_"))
    .collect(
        () -> Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder()),
        (List<StringBuilder> sb, String[] sa) -> {
            sb.get(0).append("'").append(sa[0]).append("',");
            sb.get(1).append("'").append(sa[1]).append("',");
        },
        List::addAll
    );

String ids = stringBuilders.get(0).toString();
String relids = stringBuilders.get(1).toString();
```

In short, the above uses two `StringBuilder`s, into which are accumulated the string parts (the first one holds your `ids`, the second one holds your `relids`). The main stream has `String[]` elements, each holding the two parts of the original string elements, such as `ID1_RELID1 => [ID1, RELID1]`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit off-topic answer because according to the question header a "stream" must be used which doesn't hold here. However, this approach is fast and memory friendly because there is no need to reserve memory for temporary arrays or maps.

```
String str = "ID1_RELID1,ID2_RELID2,ID3_RELID3";
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str, ",_");
StringBuilder[] sbs = new StringBuilder[] {new StringBuilder(),new StringBuilder()};
for(int i = 0; tok.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
    sbs[i%2].append(i > 1 ? ",'" : "'").append(tok.nextToken()).append("'");
}
String ids = sbs[0].toString();
String relids = sbs[1].toString();
```

Comment: ... and eye-friendly ;)

Comment: Tuned twice... at least. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you really need to stream here. May be a `regex` and two `StringBuilder`s?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "ID1_RELID1, ID2_RELID2,ID3_RELID3";

    StringBuilder left = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder right = new StringBuilder();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)_(\\w+)(,?)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        left.append("'").append(m.group(1)).append("'").append(",");
        right.append("'").append(m.group(2)).append("'").append(",");
    }

    if (left.length() > 0) {
        left.setLength(left.length() - 1);
        right.setLength(right.length() - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(left);
    System.out.println(right);

}
```

Comment: Indeed. People tend to use stream because it's trendy, not because it's convenient. At least your code is readable.

Comment: I agree. However, using `replaceAll` is even simpler. :)

Answer (score 1):

The other simple way is something like this:

first split `str` with two delimiters.(`,` & `_`)

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("_|,"));
```

then join even items of list for `ids` and odd items of list for `relids`

```
String ids = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,list.size()-1)
                       .filter(i->(i & 1) == 0)
                        .mapToObj(i-> String.format("'%s'", list.get(i).trim()))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

String relids = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,list.size())
                           .filter(i->(i & 1) == 1)
                          .mapToObj(i-> String.format("'%s'", list.get(i).trim()))
                           .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

---

if you like in one pipeline you can go with:

```
 Map<Boolean, String> result= new HashMap();
 rangeClosed(0, list.size() - 1)
         .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(i, list.get(i)))
         .collect(partitioningBy(entry -> (int) entry.getKey() % 2 == 0,
                 mapping(entry -> String.format("'%s'", entry.getValue().toString().trim()),
                            toList())))
            .forEach((k, v) -> result.put(k, String.join(",", v)));
```

then get `result.get(true)`  or `result.get(false)`

however IMO it is so verbose

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use a regex.

```
String regex = "(ID[0-9]+)_(RELID[0-9^,])";
String str = "ID1_RELID1,ID2_RELID2,ID3_RELID3";
String ids = str.replaceAll(regex, "'$1'"); // "'ID1','ID2','ID3'"
String relids = str.replaceAll(regex, "'$2'"); // "'RELID1','RELID2','RELID3'"
```

As you can see, you don't need a stream at all. Regular expression are very powerful for simple string manipulations.